# Using a target size (torch.Size([64])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results

Tags: python, pytorch

```
input_size = 200000
hidden_size = 2
num_layers = 2
num_classes = 2
batch_size = 64
num_epochs=5
```

This is my simple model

```
class GRU(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,num_layers,num_classes,batch_size):
    super(GRU,self).__init__()
    self.num_layers=num_layers
    self.hidden_size=hidden_size
    self.input_size=input_size
    self.num_classes=num_classes
    
    self.GRU_0=nn.GRU(input_size,hidden_size,num_layers*2,batch_first=True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(128, 1)
   
   
def forward(self,x):
    h0=torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2,batch_size,self.hidden_size)
    h0=weight_init(h0)
    x=x.type(torch.float32)
    #Forward Propagation
    out,_=self.GRU_0(x,h0)
    out=out.flatten()
    out=self.fc(out)
    
    return out
```

Training Loop

```
for epoch in tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
for j,data in enumerate(train_loader):
    inputs,labels=data
    outputs=model(inputs)
    print(outputs.shape)
    labels=labels.to(torch.float32)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    
    # Backward and optimize
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    if (j+1) % 64 == 0:
        print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}' 
               .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, len(train_loader), loss.item()))
```

I have to get output torch.Size([64,1]) because i set batch_size as 64. But instead of i get torch.Size([1]). Can Someone help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: We can't see how you set the dataloader, can you log `inputs.shape` and confirm it has a batch dimension? and does `outputs.shape` show size 1?

Comment: This is trainloader : train_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(loader,batch_size=batch_size). Input size 'torch.Size([64, 1, 200000])'. Output shape 'torch.Size([1])'. Batch size is 64.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your `forward`:

```
out=out.flatten()
```

Flats the entire output, including the batch dimension. Use `start_dim`:

```
out=out.flatten(start_dim=1)
```

Comment: After using start_dim=1. out is not flatten. It give torch.size([64,2]) size.

Comment: Which makes sense, since your `hidden_size` size is 2, so the output size is 2, and the batch size is 64. The problem is in your `GRU` component.

Comment: Ok.. I understand What I need to change. hidden size?

Comment: Either the hidden size or the FC layer size, depends on what you need. You can use a hidden size of `128` or a `FC` layer of size `2`. Probabily the first one.

Comment: Flatten is not done. It return torch.Size([64, 128]) output.

Comment: In your forward, log out size before the FC layer, and after. What is printed?